# Liferay blog url-rewriting

Tags: url-rewriting, blogs, liferay-6

I am using liferay 6.1 and i have already shortened the url of the blog using url rewriting but still i have the problem in the url.
The url gets showed up like this `localhost:8080/blog/-/blogs/testing`, but i want to change the url to this `localhost:8080/blog/blogs/testing` inshort i want to remove the `-` from the url.

Any help will be apprecicated, I am trying this from very long but cannot find the solution.

Answer (score 2):

You could try doing this using the [urlrewrite.xml](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/manual/2.6/) file that you can use in Liferay, but a better option would be to put Liferay behind an Apache Reverse Proxy and use the rewriting capabilities of that: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html